# <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000000000433DB38>

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I'm developing a Pymongo project using Flask Framework. **I want to fetch data and assign it to a variable something like this.**

```
dOcName = select name from doctors where dname = "<some_name>";
```

Below is my Flask and html code when i run, I'm getting printed `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000000000433DB38>` in my textbox.

**app.py:**

```
@app.route('/dochome',methods=['POST','GET'])
def dochome():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(session) == 0:
            return render_template('login.html')
    uname = session['username']
    dOcName = db.doctors.find({'dname': uname},{'name':1, '_id':0})
    return render_template('dochome.html', dname = uname, dOcName = dOcName)
```

**dochome.html:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('dochome') }}">
<div class="container">
    <h3>WELCOME: Doctor. <input class="form-control" type="text" name="docName" value="{{ dOcName }}" readonly></h3>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong/how I can get **dOcName** I am looking for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if i use `dOcName = db.doctors.find_one({'dname': uname},{'name':1, '_id':0})` i'm getting result as `{'name': '<Doc_name>'}` I want only `<Doc_name>`

Comment: Then do `dOcName = db.doctors.find_one({'dname': uname},{'name':1, '_id':0})['name']` and simply access the value of the property in the dict. So it's a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your time @NeilLunn I found the result.